# Does NewStringUTF copy the const char * passed in

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

Official JNI API does specify if the copy is made while creating a `jstring` from `const char *`. Here is the quote:

```
NewStringUTF
jstring NewStringUTF(JNIEnv *env, const char *bytes);
```

> Constructs a new `java.lang.String` object from an array of characters
>   in modified UTF-8 encoding.

Does it mean the copy of `const char *` is made or I have to `strdup` it by myself?

Comment: @apangin Thanks. This is not directly related to the original question, but in case I'm iterating through a large array and for each element of the array I create `jstring` string and set it to some object. Is it a good practice (or necessary) to call `DeleteLocalRef` for that created `jstring` on each iteration?

Comment: In such cases `DeleteLocalRef` makes sence. When there are too many unused (but not deleted) JNI local references, allocation of new references will suffer from the overhead of walking through a linked list of `JNIHandleBlock`s.

Comment: I've converted the comment to the answer. As to your second question, JNI spec [explicitly says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/design.html#global-and-local-references) about this particular example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NewStringUTF` creates a new String object in Java Heap. The string is backed by a `byte[]` or `char[]` array in Java Heap, and it does not share any off-heap data you pass in.

So, you don't need `strdup`, the contents will be copied (and possibly converted) to Java Heap anyway.

Comment: Will this new string be handled by the garbage collector then ?

Comment: @btbbass Yes, it will be a regular managed object